# ListDensityPlot does not produce correct graphics

Tags: plotting

Could anyone help me with ListDensityPlot? Here is my Mathematica
 code:

```
    ta = Table[{x = RandomReal[{0, 1}], y = RandomReal[{0, 1}], 
    x}, {10000}];
px = ListDensityPlot[ta, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, GrayLevel[x]]];
py = ListDensityPlot[ta, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, GrayLevel[y]]];
pz = ListDensityPlot[ta, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, GrayLevel[z]]];
pxyz = GraphicsRow[{px, py, pz}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

The tresult is as follows:
[image]

I cannot understand, why the first picture and the last one are not identical. The second picture is not correct either: it should have a gradient character as the first one (rotated by 90 degrees).

Comment: Yes it is. The table for ListDensityPlot must be created of 3 numbers: x,y, z=f(x,y).

Comment: **Read the documentation**. `ColorFunction` for `ListDensityPlot` takes one variable: the density variable $z=f(x,y)$. Your colour function has 3 variable slots.  The first one is the only one that has a value in all three of your cases.  The number of variables `ColorFunction` has differs depending on the function it is used in.  Look at the function's documentation and/or `ColorFunction`'s documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if you copy `ta1 = ta`, the plot whit

```
pz=ListDensityPlot[ta1, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, GrayLevel[z]]]
```

it's the first, I guess that the funtión it's changing

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the case.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you search, but i do this

Answer (score 0):

```
nat = 1000;
posi = Table[{0, 0, 0, 0}, {i, 1, nat}];
posi2 = Table[{0, 0, 0, 0}, {i, 1, nat}];
n = nat^(1/3);
cont = 1;
del = 0.01;

Do[Do[{posi[[cont]] = {del*i, del*j, del*i}, cont = cont + 1}, {i, 1, 
    n}], {j, 1, n}];

plot = Table[posi[[i]], {i, 1, cont - 1}];
px = ListDensityPlot[plot];

plot = Table[{posi[[i, 1]], posi[[i, 2]], nn - i}, {i, 1, cont - 1}];
py = ListDensityPlot[plot];

plot = Table[{posi[[i, 1]], posi[[i, 2]], -posi[[i, 3]]}, {i, 1, 
    cont - 1}];
pz = ListDensityPlot[plot];

GraphicsRow[{px, py, pz}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]